# Why can I not perform the delete operation on my question

Tags: support, vote-to-delete

I have a question on SO and it has some down votes. So I want to delete my question, if it is not good or not clear then why can I not delete my question? It shows me message that

> your question has answers and you cant delete your question

Is this a rule that if a question has some answers and it also has downvotes, that we can't delete our question?

Comment: @rene not duplicate there is difference in my question

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: @Engineer the info. is there, eg: the owner of a question can't delete their own question if it has any upvoted answer... but there could well be a better dupe for it...

Comment: @JonClements but my question dosnt have up vote it has down votes

Comment: @Engineer You can't delete it if it has upvoted _answers_ .Your profile shows only 1 question with a negative score, and that question has upvoted answers.

Comment: @S.L.Barth you are right my qustion has some answers and also these answers has some up votes... it means i cant do any thing with my qusetion?

Comment: If you _really_ want it deleted, you could flag it for moderator attention and ask to have it deleted. But you should make a compelling case. Just because a question is getting downvotes, is not enough reason to delete it.

Comment: @S.L.Barth i just want to know the reason that why i cant delete the qestion and now i got my answer i didnt want to delete my question